# Using Java ProcessBuilder, how do I run a process located in a unix home directory?

Tags: java, unix, processbuilder, home-directory

We have a Java server-client application that allows us to run processes on different boxes (i.e. the clients), which are started by the Java [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I want to run a process that will be copied/synced to the user's home directory (i.e. the user who started the client).

How do I reference the unix home directory in the `String` that is passed to the `ProcessBuilder`? (Due to the design of the server-client application, only a String of the process, args etc. is passed to the ProcessBuilder.)

It works if I state the home directory explicitly:

- `/home/user/processes/process.sh`

However, that assumes that I know which user is running the client. (Part of the design is that we can switch/substitute boxes/clients to run jobs, without necessarily knowing who started the client on a given box.)

I've also tried, but to no avail:

- `$HOME/processes/process.sh`
- `~/processes/process.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the approach I took was to pass the script and its arguments to bash - along the lines of:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "$HOME/processes/process.sh args");
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that both ~ and $HOME are only understood by your shell, probably BASH, not by ProcessBuilder or Java.

$HOME should be available via the property `user.home`. See [System Properties documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

i.e.

```
File fullpath = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "processes/process.sh");
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(fullpath.getAbsolutePath());
```

or could call it relative to current directory

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("processes/process.sh");
processBuilder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
```

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful in steering me to a viable solution. In my context, neither of the above was practical, as the command passed to the ProcessBuilder is literally a String, and there isn't scope to configure the ProcessBuilder relative to the System properties.

Answer (score 0):

From a command line, both `$HOME` and `~` are expanded to a user's home directory by the shell.

`ProcessBuilder` runs the process directly with no shell, so those expansions will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Not tried it myself but that should work:

Change into the home before and then execute the process.sh

`cd && ./processes/process.sh`

Comment: No. This will not work.  `cd` as posted here is a *shell command*.  `ProcessBuilder` doesn't run the child process under a shell.  Guessing at answers really should earn you a downvote.